# Can I choose a particular country IP address range?

Tags: configuration

When I'm out of the country, I want to make it look like I'm still there without a different country IP address.

Is this possible and if so how please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ExitNodes` directive in your torrc to specify which exit nodes your Tor may use. You can specify exit nodes by ip/mask, by nick or fingerprint, or by country. You can specify a country using the country code in curly brackets: {us} for United States, {ch} for Switzerland, etc..

Additionally, you can enable `StrictNodes` to make sure that Tor will stick to your specified exit nodes even if that means failure.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this please or point me to instructions? Thanks.